# Categorical bar chart in bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have a dataframe

```
    Experience  Microsoft  SAS  Salesforce
0     1 To 3          38   29          48
1   12 To 18           4    2           4
2     3 To 8          46   22          45
3    8 To 12          12    6           8
```

In this I want Experience in x axis and Microsft,SAS,Salesforce in y axis

what I tried till now:

table2 = pd.read_csv('Experience.csv')

full=table2.columns.tolist()
full_val=table2.values.T.tolist()

tech=table2.drop(['Experience'] , axis=1,)
he=tech.max()

data = {}

for i in range(len(full)):
    data[full[i]] = full_val[i]

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=table2['Experience'],
                                    y=value1))


p = figure(x_range=exp, y_range=(0, 50), plot_height=350, title="Experience wise opening",
           toolbar_location=None, tools="")


p.vbar(x=dodge('x', -0.25, range=p.x_range), top='y', width=0.2, source=source,
            legend=value(key))


p.show()
```

It shows only the last value of index that is salesforce .. I want to show all the values;

Answer (score 1):

There were some more small mistakes in the code so it didn't show anything on my laptop. The code below should work and give the desired output.

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LabelSet
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import dodge
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis

data = {'Experience': ['1 To 3', '12 To 18', '3 To 8', '8 To 12'], 'Microsoft': [38, 4, 46, 12], 'SAS': [29, 2, 22, 6], 'Salesforce': [48, 4, 45, 8]}
source = ColumnDataSource(data)
exp = data['Experience']
ys = list(data.keys())
ys.remove('Experience')
TOOLTIPS = [("Experience", "@Experience")]
p = figure(x_range=exp, y_range=(0, 60), plot_height=350, title="Experience wise opening", tooltips=TOOLTIPS)
colorList = Viridis[len(ys)]
labels = []
for y, offset, color in zip(ys, [-0.25, 0, 0.25], colorList):
    labels = LabelSet(x=dodge('Experience', offset, range=p.x_range), y=y, text=y, source=source, text_align='center')
    p.vbar(x=dodge('Experience', offset, range=p.x_range), top=y, width=0.2, source=source, legend=y + ' ', color=color)
    p.add_layout(labels)
    TOOLTIPS.append((y, "@"+y))
p.legend.click_policy="hide"
show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but it is static..what is i dont know the name of Top

Comment: Edited my answer. The name of the key with the list with x axis values has to be the same. The name of top values can be different now. You still have to supply the offset when the number of tops is different. If you also want this to be generated I would suggest to use a different approach like in this example: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#nested-categories.

Comment: how to add tooltips and data label  on same data..i did but it is ovrlapping

Comment: I updated my answer and added a labels and a hovertool. This hovertool shows all the y values for an x value. It is possible to show only one y value per bar but this requires you to create three different hover tools.

Comment: i applied.. but my first index value is not coming..when i hover it..showing ? in  microsoft

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot with the problem? The code in my answer works fine on my machine.

Comment: Just posting this here, shouldn't be in my answer; https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIj5y.png
It looks like you are using an old or edited version of the code since it doesn't show the toolbar/labels and it does show the toolbar/labels in my example. Try to copy the code again, it should work.

Comment: Why are you converting your Pandas dataframe to a dictionary? ColumnDataSource also accepts dataframes ;) (I just used a dictionary so the answer doesn't require other people to make the CSV file themselves.). So just use pandas to read your CSV file and edit `source = ColumnDataSource(dataFrame)`